# How to make Bootstrap Scrollspy dark-themed instead of primary-themed (blue)

Tags: frontend, themes, navbar, scrollspy

In the official Bootstrap documentation on scrollspy, the example of the navbar uses a primary theme (or looks like a blue color):

```
<nav id="navbar-example2" class="navbar bg-body-tertiary px-3 mb-3">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading1">First</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#scrollspyHeading2">Second</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#scrollspyHeading3">Third</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#scrollspyHeading4">Fourth</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#scrollspyHeading5">Fifth</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-example2" data-bs-root-margin="0px 0px -40%" data-bs-smooth-scroll="true" class="scrollspy-example bg-body-tertiary p-3 rounded-2" tabindex="0">
  <h4 id="scrollspyHeading1">First heading</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="scrollspyHeading2">Second heading</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="scrollspyHeading3">Third heading</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="scrollspyHeading4">Fourth heading</h4>
  <p>...</p>
  <h4 id="scrollspyHeading5">Fifth heading</h4>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

[image: Scrollspy Bootstrap]

As you can see in the image above, it uses a primary theme (or looks like a blue-themed color).

How can I make it dark themed or something like noir themed instead of primary themed so that it will be more suitable if I want to apply it to a noir themed website frontend design?

Suppose my website design looks like this:

[image: My Website Design]